# Android Compose How do I set the system bars (both status and navigation bars) to same as my TopAppBar container color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, background-color, statusbar, jetpack-compose-accompanist

As the title indicates, I want to set the system-bars (status and navigation bars) to have the same color as my `TopAppBar` container color, which has a default color of `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface`.

I have attempted the above in the following code:

```
import com.google.accompanist.systemuicontroller.rememberSystemUiController

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
            SideEffect {
                systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
                )
            }
            MeganurseryResourceMgtTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    AppNavigation()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the user changes the theme from light to dark and viceversa, I am assuming the system bars will also change their colors.

But I get a complier error with a red line under the keyword `colorScheme` and with the following error:

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

Please help.
thank you

Comment: The problem is that `setSystemBarsColor` from Accompanist System UI Controller is not a composable function, therefore, you cannot call the composable parameters and functions within it. Usually this type of configuration you are trying to apply is made on theme file (on your `MeganurseryResourceMgtTheme`). You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75539202/system-navigation-bar-is-applying-a-dark-effect-in-some-scenarios) (and the answer) that have what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I will implement your suggestion and post back the result here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue, thanks to @Thales Isidoro, by removing the following code I had written in `MainActivity.kt`file.

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
            SideEffect {
                systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
                )
            }
```

And I modified the following line in the `MeganurseryResourceMgtTheme`

```
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            (view.context as Activity).window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.surface.toArgb()
            ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(view)?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }
```